# Fabric.js: Problems with stroke color and width svg files on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I'm using in my project fabricJS and I have problem to change stroke color and  width. I have some SVG files on my page and after clicking user can add this SVG to canvas and modify its properties. With fill it works perfectly but with stroke I can't do the same. This is code for fill and it is working good:

```
function setImageColor(element) 
{
    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject(),
    color = "#"+element.value;

    console.log(color)    
    console.log(activeObject)
    activeObject.set({fill : color});
    canvas.renderAll();
}

jscolor.addEventListener('change', function()
{
    setImageColor(this);
});
```

Here is code for loading SVG elements on canvas:

```
shapes.forEach(function(e)
{
    e.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        var src = e.src;
        fabric.loadSVGFromURL( src, function(objects, options) 
        {
            var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
            canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
            obj.scaleToHeight(127) 
                .scaleToWidth(90)
                .center() 
                .setCoords();
            canvas.setActiveObject(obj).renderAll();
        });
    });
});
```

and here is code for the stroke and it is not working:

```
function setStrokeColor(element) 
{
    color = "#"+element.value;
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    console.log(color)    
    console.log(activeObject)
    activeObject.set({stroke : color, strokeWidth: 5});
    canvas.renderAll();
}

var stroke = document.getElementById("stroke");
console.log(stroke)

stroke.addEventListener('change', function()
{
    setStrokeColor(this);
});
```

Comment: Can you add your SVG?  I'm guessing the SVG will need to be modified to allow you to "stroke".  In the past I've had to have my graphics artist (who uses Adobe Illustrator) tweak when exporting so it formats different allowing it to play nicer with the html 5 canvas object - http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/convert-primitive-to-path-using-svg-format-in-illustrator.

Comment: I'm also using Adobe Illustrator to create svg files. On fidlejs code for circle from AI. I'm going to make a lot of shapes, moe dificult like plane or flower. https://jsfiddle.net/ck75a2r3/

Comment: HTML 5 Canvas might not like Circle, try exporting from Adobe as path...  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/convert-primitive-to-path-using-svg-format-in-illustrator

Comment: This was the [Bad SVG](https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/teLde5pr/) with Rect and Circle, this was the [Good SVG](https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/ssc37ejc/) with Path that I could manipulate with HTML 5 Canvas and FabricJS.

Comment: Thaks. I made the path from svg, but it is still not working. I want to edit the svg when they are on canvas. I'm using Fabric.js library not a standard canvas.

Comment: Can you upload your new svg?

Comment: The new one: https://jsfiddle.net/ck75a2r3/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (thanks for the SVG Path export):

[image: fabricjs svg stroke fill color]

Here's the FabricJS code:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromString('<svg id="Warstwa_1" data-name="Warstwa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 70 70"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}</style></defs><title>generator ikon</title><path class="cls-1" d="M60,35A25,25,0,1,1,35,10,25,25,0,0,1,60,35Z"/></svg>', function(objects, options) {
  var shape = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  shape.set({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    scaleX: 3,
    scaleY: 3
  });
  if (shape.paths) {
    for (var i = 0; i < shape.paths.length; i++) {
      shape.paths[i].set({
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'green',
        strokeWidth: 5
      });
    }
  }
  object = shape;
  canvas.add(shape);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
var switchColors = true;
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (object.paths) {
    for (var i = 0; i < object.paths.length; i++) {
      object.paths[i].set({
        fill: (switchColors ? 'green' : 'red'),
        stroke: (switchColors ? 'red' : 'green'),
        strokeWidth: (switchColors ? 10 : 5)
      });
    }
  }
  switchColors = !switchColors;
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Here's the all important JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/wg2qxc8e/.

Let me know if you have anymore questions.  I hope it helps!

Comment: No worries, I had to work through the same idiosyncrasies when I was changing SVG's that were loaded onto the HTML 5 Canvas and using FabricJS.  If you'd be so kind as to mark my answer as "helpful" and/or "accepeted" for the next person, that'd be great.  Feel free to post any other  questions, I can try to help further.